# Cakephp 2.0 captcha component gives warning

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using Captcha component with cakephp 2.0. Though Its going well but my traced issue with this component.

```
Warning: Argument 1 passed to Component::__construct() must be an instance of ComponentCollection, none given, called in ...
```

When I tried to find solution it gives me two line code in somewhere comment.

```
_controller = $collection->getController();
parent::__construct($collection, $settings);

function startup( ) {
     $this->Controller = $this->_controller;
}
```

The solution code is something like this which ended me with error.

Captcha component link is http://www.devarticles.in/

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution for Cakephp 2.0. In controller where you are creating instance do it like this..

```
$myvideo = new MyVideoComponent(new ComponentCollection()); //make instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Please download working Captcha Component for CakePHP 2.x from [author's website](http://www.devarticles.in/cakephp/simple-captcha-component-for-cakephp/)